# Sometimes I get flag decline reasons that don't make sense

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

For example, this flag on [Agent job that emails from custom email table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19568792/1214743):

> I think this should be migrated to Code Review or Database. – Malachi Oct 24 at 16:28
>   *declined - The unfortunate outcome of all of those "Show Your Work" comments has been folks dumping big chunks of code into their questions when it's not strictly needed.*

This is not a complaint - it's just that I would like the reason to be clear, so that I don't flag something the same way only to have it declined (with the side effect of annoying a moderator).

Comment: all the answers and comments make it clear why it is hard to get the questions migrated to Code Review.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this particular case, I suspect a 'fat finger' decline. Mysticial's answer is absolutely generally applicable in cases like this, but looking at the flagging history on that post, the decline reason does not seem to match up to any flags.

My guess is the decliner of that flag meant to decline and enter that reason on a different post. There were no such comments on that question, and it's not related to your flag.

That said; I don't know enough about Code Review to know if that's a proper question to be migrated there.

Comment: it's working code and the OP is looking for a better or more efficient way to write the code to accomplish what he is doing, and I think that fits for Code Review.

Comment: Dammit. What I can't see. I can't smell either...

Comment: @Malachi That sounds right. Pretty sure they are completely off-topic on SO.

Comment: so should this flag be looked at again, or would you agree it should be declined?

Comment: @Malachi I am generally very careful about migrating questions if I don't know the target site *very* well. I'll migrate to Server Fault and Super User, or when a known highly-active member on a site requests it to be migrated there. Other than that, I don't touch such flags myself. That said, it does seem like an appropriate site for that question, yes.

Answer (score 6):

That response you got was likely directed at someone else who flagged the same post.

Moderators can't selectively respond to each flag. They can only do it all at once and to everybody who flagged.

Comment: There's only one flag on the post. I think the person who processed the flag either just made a logical leap (or two) to get from the flag to the decline message, or they meant to post that message on a flag on a different post.

Comment: I did not know that.  so do all the flags just show as a flag and not by category or whatever?

Comment: @Malachi I believe mods can see all the flags and who flagged. But the mod cannot validate/decline them individually and cannot respond to each flag with a different message.